# Hiding header on scroll with jquery

Tags: jquery, header, addclass

I'm trying to have my page not show a header until the user scrolls 600px. I've come up with the code below by parsing through the jquery docs, but I can't seem to make it work. A little help in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: I've figured it out. I had the selector period before the class name. I'm not seeing the duration transition fire though. *$("header").removeClass("header-hidden", **1000**);* Any advice there?

**HTML**

```
 <header class="header-fixed header-hidden shadow">
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
 </header>
```

**CSS**

```
.header-fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }
.header-hidden { display: none;  }
header { z-index: 999; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; height: 70px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); position: relative; }
```

**Jquery**

```
    <script>
      $(window).scroll(function () { 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 600) {
          $("header").removeClass("header-hidden", 1000);
        }
                else
                  $("header").addClass("header-hidden", 1000);
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is "1000" in addClass?  What are you trying to do ?
$("header").addClass("header-hidden", 1000);

Comment: I was trying to add a transition, but it looks like the .addClass/.removeClass functions require a click event. I used paniclater's advice to simply use the .fadeIn and .fadeOut animation functions and this gave me the desired outcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you intention is to hide the header until user hits 600px. I would recommend changing your CSS so that header is hidden by default then just do a simple jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` when needed

## CSS:

```
header { 
  background: #ccc; 
  display: none;
  height: 70px; 
  left: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999; 
}
```

## jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 600) {
      $('header').hide();
    } else {
      $('header').show();
    }
  });
});​
```

​
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pwLZ/1/)

One thing you have wrong is `removeClass()` does not have a transition argument. Only the class argument without the `.`

Comment: if you do want to transition them in, `hide` and `show` do allow you to insert a time in milliseconds like this `hide(1000)` would be 1 second

Comment: Thanks man. I was racking my brain for a while trying to write an even more complex function. The .hide/.show solution works great, however I ended up using the .slideIn function instead so that the header appeared from out of the browser chrome. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the class, you dont have to specify "." (dot).

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 600) {
      $(this).addClass("header-hidden");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: For transition you could set the css with transition-duration with 1000 in jquery.

Ex: $(this).css('transition-duration','1000s');

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the second part of your question:

"I'm not seeing the duration transition fire though. $("header").removeClass("header-hidden", 1000); Any advice there?"

I checked the jQuery api and it doesn't look like removeClass can take a transition option.

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

If you want the Header to fade in as an animation and fade out as an animation you are going to want to use a jQuery animation function. For example

$("header").fadeIn(1000);

$("header").fadeOut(1000);

A link to all the jQuery "effects" you can apply is here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Hope that helps!